# How to do I initialise Swift array of object eg. CALayer

Tags: swift

I was able to initialise CALayer using method 1 which is properly working in the rest of code but not method 2. Could you please advise the what is wrong.

Initialise CALayer

```
var layers:[CALayer]!
```

Method 1. is working

```
layers = [CALayer(), CALayer(), CALayer(), CALayer(), CALayer(), CALayer(), CALayer(), CALayer()]
```

Method 2. is not working

```
layers = [CALayer](count: 8, repeatedValue: CALayer())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 2 doesn't work because that initializer installs the exact same value in every index of the array.

You can use method one, or you can use a for loop:

```
var layers = [CALayer]()
layers.reserveCapacity(layerCount)

let layerCount = 10
for (_ in 1... layerCount)
{
  layers.append(CALayer())
}
```

(I'm still getting used to Swift so that syntax might not be perfect, but it should give you the general idea)

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity, it looks like there is no minimumCapacity initializer for Arrays like there is for Dictionaries? Seems like an omission. I bet creating an array and then expanding it's capacity does 2 allocations, wheres the `Dictionary(minimumCapacity)` form only does a single allocation.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `map` and an interval:

```
layers = (0..<8).map { _ in CALayer() }
```

The `_ in` is an annoyance that shouldn’t be necessary but Swift’s type inference currently needs it.

The `map` approach has a big advantage over a `for`-based approach, since it means you can declare `layers` with `let` if it isn’t going to need to change further later:

```
let layers = (0..<8).map { _ in CALayer() }
```

It may also be marginally more efficient vs multiple `appends`, since the size of the array can be calculated ahead of time by `map`, vs `append` needing to resize the array multiple times as it grows.

Comment: I like your approach better than mine. (I edited my code to reserve capacity for the number of layers to be created, but the map statement accomplishes the same thing in a single line. BTW, I gotta know. Laden or unladen?